# При прокрутке страницы добавляет класс

Tags: javascript, jquery

На сайте  не нашёл, как можно при прокрутке страницы добавить класс. Вот мой код, нужно,  когда я прокрутил `106px` - мне добавился класс, ну к примеру `custom` и наоборот.

```js
<script>
var h_hght = 106; // высота моей шапки
var h_mrg = 0;    // отступ, когда шапка уже не видна                
$(function(){ 
    var elem = $('#menu'); //Добавить сюда класс
    var top = $(this).scrollTop();     
    if(top > h_hght){
        elem.css('top', h_mrg);
    }                
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        top = $(this).scrollTop();         
        if (top+h_mrg < h_hght) {
            elem.css('top', (h_hght-top));
        } else {
            elem.css('top', h_mrg);
        }
   
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ещё один пример, логика работает и после перезагрузки страницы։

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var h_hght = 106;
    var height = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (height >= h_hght) {
        $('#menu').addClass('custom');
    } else {
        $('#menu').removeClass('custom');
    }


    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var height = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (height >= h_hght) {
            $('#menu').addClass('custom');
        } else {
            $('#menu').removeClass('custom');
        }
    });


});
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я верно понял то вот так это делается на jQuery

integer - заменить на нужную величину

elem - нужный элемент

new - новый `class` который надо присвоить

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= integer) {
        $("elem").addClass("new");
    } else {
        $("elem").removeClass("new");
    }
});
```